# How to parse pdf using tika library

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, apache-tika, text-extraction

I am trying to parse a pdf file using `tika` library but I am getting this complicated error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/olivia/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/home/olivia/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 83, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/olivia/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Code

```
import tika
from tika import parser
parsed = parser.from_file('simple1.pdf')
print(parsed["content"])
```

Same error is comming while using its wrapper

```
from tikapp import TikaApp
tika_client = TikaApp(file_jar="/opt/tika/tika-app-1.15.jar")
tika_client.extract_only_content("simple1.pdf")
```

For detailed error [see](http://pasted.co/4ed65483)

Answer (score 0):

Please specify full path in the pdf name and use forwards slashes for eg:

```
from tika import parser
```

`parsedPDF=parser.from_file('C:/Users/xyzuser/Documents/abc.pdf')
parsedPDF`

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the tika jars(tika-app.jar, tika-server.jar and tika-server.jar.md5) from [https://tika.apache.org/download.html][1]
2. Keep these jars(renamed as : tika-app.jar, tika-server.jar and tika-server.jar.md5) in the */tmp* folder for Linux and in C:\Users<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\ for Windows

   `from tika import parser`

   `parsedPDF = parser.from_file("/path/to/file/my_pdf.pdf")`

   `print(parsedPDF["metadata"])`

   `print(parsedPDF["content"].encode('ascii', errors='ignore')`

Answer (score -1):

You just have to make a small modification to your code as below:

parsed = parser.from_file('simple1.pdf',‘http://localhost:9998/tika’)

Worked for me, hopefully works for you as well :)